# 98 GMC 1500 SLT ac electrical problem

Tags: ac, gmc, truck

I developed a leak in the high side Schraeder valve and the refrigerant got low enough that the compressor kept cycling on and off. I unplugged the compressor coil wire until I had time to fix the leak and vacuum down the system and recharge it. When I plugged in the coil wire, the compressor would not come on. I had to get another connector wired to the battery and the ground and got it charged up and plugged in the original truck plug and the compressor still does not come on. What do I need to look for? Thanks

Comment: What engine do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Check the pressure cycling switch on the accumulator. Should have continuity above approximately 45 psi and open below 25 psi. The switch just screws off and there is a Schrader valve in the fitting so you will not loose any refrigerant when removing it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's like mine ('92 C1500) you might have to reset the A/C controller.  The simple way is disconnect the battery for a minute.